# Import Error States File is outside of src/ folder when the file is for sure really inside of src/

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I was attempting to build a practice project to learn Redux. I'm getting an error message saying that the file I'm importing is outside of src/ but the file is for sure located inside of src/. I've tried changing my folder structure, migrating my code to a new React App and the error proceeds. I really just want to understand the source of this error so that I can avoid it in the future.

The error message, screenshot of my folder structure is below. I've also included the `Users` component where the import error occurs.

Thank you for your time!

[image: File Structure]

Error Message:

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./src/Users.js 4:0-43
>
> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../FakeData.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
> You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

```js
    import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import { UsersData } from '../FakeData.js';
    
    export const userSlice = createSlice({
            name: 'users',
            initialState: {value: UsersData },
            reducers: {
                addUser: (state, action) => {
                    // Write code for adding a user 
                }
            },
            
        }
    );
    
    export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: It should be `import { UsersData } from './FakeData.js'`. As every import is relative to `src` path and `User.js` is already in `src` and `FakeData.js` is sibling (same level) so you don't have to go to parent folder `..`

Answer (score 0):

The import needs to be `import { UsersData } from './FakeData.js'`.

Not: import `{ UsersData } from '../FakeData.js';`

The extra period in `../FakeDate.js` was causing the error by telling it to look outside of the src folder.

This was a simple copy and paste error. When I migrated the App and changed the folder structure I forgot to take away one of the periods. I will be asking a follow up question about why I got the error before migrating the App. In that scenario the complier was looking inside of the same folder that Users.js is located in even with `../FakeDate.js` directing it go back outside of the features folder.